# How should I enable specific users to enter a configuration mode on a Kiosk?

Tags: kiosk

I am building an App which will be installed on a Kiosk, the Kiosk's sole purpose is to run this app and prevent users from doing anything else beside than use the app.

After installation only authorised users will be able to view existing configurations and modify them after entering their credentials, obviously I would not want members of the public to enter this mode or know about it's existence.

Currently I have a few options on my mind but not entirely satisfied with any:

1. Upon entering a magic value, the configuration mode login wizard
   will appear.
2. A hidden field on the screen, that will bring up the configuration
   mode login wizard upon being clicked.
3. A button that will only appear on the splash screen.

Comment: Will the kiosk have any hardware keys/buttons you can utilize?

Comment: @dennislees Nope, just on screen buttons

Answer (score 2):

What we usually do is add an area on the screen that is not a visible action item (e.g. one of the corners of the screen, or a section of a logo), and require the admin to press on it for a few seconds (somewhere between 3 and 6, usually), without any visible feedback until the full time of course.

If using a touch screen, make sure it’s wide enough for a finger, and test it on the actual device, including any furniture/holder, as edges are sometimes hard to reach.

This will then open a dialog/modal requiring a pin before being able to go any further.

You also want to automatically close that dialog after a timeout (something like 30 seconds) in the event someone still managed to open it.

Alternatives depend on the physical setup and hardware, it may involve RFID / NFC tags, remote management, having to plug in a keyboard, special inputs (including special bar codes if applicable)...

Comment: I've used the corners phantom areas thing, but is better if there are a sequence for it: is as simple as having a buffer with the last 3 or 4 areas pressed that clears out every n seconds, then you get the enter code/pin

Answer (score 1):

**Utilize existing UI to invoke a number pad to input passcode**

Your first idea, combination of keystrokes to pull up a login mode makes the most sense. A hidden button or a button on the splash screen are likely to pressed by accident or out of curiosity.

**Holding Key Combinations**

As with certain computer hardware, where in order to enter certain modes it's required to e.g. start up, then hold down a key combination until the splash screen appears, consider letting a certain combination of simultaneously held keys invoke a number pad, into which a passcode can be typed.

**Leveraging Existing Inputs**

It's possible to enter types of admin mode on some cell phones by typing a certain combination of numbers and special characters into the keypad. e.g. 188090#* If you don't have a keypad, you might leverage any existing input field where it's possible to free type and submit.